# Help me translate the red signature seal on this picture?

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context, simplified-characters, character-identification, seal

I inherited these pictures from my grandmother who bought them in China in 1980-81. I have had a difficult time trying to translate the red artist signature seals. I have tried image translator app, I looked on several different Asian artists signature websites and poured through pictures to try and find something similar. Pleco wasn't as helpful as I had hoped. I also tried ibiblio.org, which alerted me to the fact that the red deal was in fact a signature. I would also love to know the translation of the rest of the characters that are written on each one. I really want to have a clear understanding of what I've got and after 3 hours of searching I am no closer.  I am just starting to learn about this so for now, the simpler the explanation the better. Please help!!!

**Chinese Etching**

[image]

**Chinese Silk Embroidery Panel**

[image]

**Chinese Silk embroidery Panel**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is there an English translation for the family name?

Comment: You can check [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%BC%98).

Answer (score 1):

i agreed with @droooze that, the 2nd & 3rd seal is "湘綉":

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=湘](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%B9%98)

綉 (u+7d89) is a variant of 繡 (u+7d61), which means embroider

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=繡](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E7%B9%A1)

then, the 1st seal, i recognised it as "石氏"

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=石](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E7%9F%B3)

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=氏](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%B0%8F)

in which "石" is the surname, matched the "writer"'s name "石鍾璵"

the text of the 2nd picture is "活潑玲瓏", roughly vivacious & exquisite

the text of the 3rd picture is "活潑天真", roughly lively & artless

need to explain text of the first one?

have fun :)

Comment: Ahh..石..my mistake

Comment: frankly, i'm astonished to read your suggestion of "弘"  ^ o ^

Comment: Yes! Plz explain the 1st one. I've have researched til my eyes are broken to try and figure out exactly who the artist is on the 1st one. Thank you!!!

Comment: So on the first one the characters in English mean ShiShi...does that mean anything as far as artist go?

Comment: Is the artist Shi Zhongyu??

Comment: well, "石氏" just means a person with his surname (氏) as (石). yea, the artist is 石鍾璵

Comment: Just to clarify: _artless_ has several quite different meanings in English; as a translation of 天真, only the senses that denote ‘innocent, straightforward, free of deceit or pretence’ are relevant – not the ones that relate to clumsiness or a lack of skill or knowledge.

Comment: Can anyone tell me what the text in 1st pic says? I've got the seal figured out, but would like to translate the calligraphy.

Answer (score 0):

图1：应该是一副画上的题字，原文有些不太清楚，个别字我辨识不出。
意思是：这幅图的名字叫踏雪寻梅，画与甲申十年三月下旬，为一个号玉壶山人的老人贺寿，画的作者是这个老人的侄子。